# Complex Analysis Identity

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that for all z,w $\in\mathbb C$

$\frac{Im(z\bar w)}{zw}$ = $\frac{Im(z)}{z}$ - $\frac{Im(w)}{w}$

Any tips to prove this?

Comment: Write $\text{Im}(z)=(z-\overline z)/(2i)$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z = r_1(\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha), w = r_2(\cos \beta + i\sin \beta)$. Then we need
$$\frac{\sin(\alpha - \beta)}{e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}} = \frac{\sin\alpha}{e^{i\alpha}} - \frac{\sin \beta}{e^{i\beta}}$$
Thus we need
$$\sin(\alpha - \beta) = (\cos \beta+i\sin \beta)\sin\alpha - (\cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha)\sin \beta$$
Expanding the right side, this follows.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to showing that $\Im(z\bar w)=w\Im(z)-z\Im(w)$

Now, notice that the imaginary parts in $w\Im(z)-z\Im(w)$ cancel out and we're left with $\Re(w)\Im(z)-\Re(z)\Im(w)=\Re(\bar w)\Im(z)+\Re(z)\Im(\bar w)=|z\bar w|$ as required.